# Enforcing a business rule involving multiple items

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design

Let's say that I got a simple todolist:

```
interface ITodoList
{
  ITodoItem Create(title);
  IEnumerable<ITodoItem> Items {get;}
}
interface ITodoITem
{
    void StartTrackTime();
    void StopTrackTime();
}
```

Now I want to enforce so that time is only tracked for one item at a time (per user).

Should I create a domain event like `ItemTimeTrackingStarted` that `StartTrackTime` generates. The event would be picked up by a `ITodoService` which checks if there are any other time tracked items for the current user (and stop them). Or are there a better way?

Comment: IMO, ITodoService would be named ITodoPolicy, because it is trying enforce a rule and not execute a transaction. If the tracked TodoItem is the first into TodoList, you are working with a FIFO collection, right?

Comment: Aren't you missing something like TodoList.AssignItemTo(User user) or UserTimeTracking.StartTrackingTimeFor(TodoItem item)?

Answer (score 1):

well if you have dependencies between the items, which in the case is the check, my proposal would be to move the track method into the todo list object, and away from item.

So you request a change from the object that holds all todo items, and there you locate the checks as well.

Comment: isn't that a bit illogical? since it's not the list that the time will be tracked for?

Comment: I agree with Martin's approach.  The `TodoList` is the aggregate.  It should be enforcing invariants.

Comment: Please add an example showing how you structure the entities.

Comment: Isn't it better to put the `TrackTime` method on the `User` instead?

Comment: for me it doesn't matter on which object you acutally adding some numbers, the point is to implement the code where it suits best, and for me that is the List. It acts like a facade.

Answer (score 1):

IMO I'd do it like this, I don't know all the details of the context, but for this specific functionality here it goes

```
 public interface ITrackTime
 {

    void StartTrackTime();
    void StopTrackTime();
 }
 public interface ITodoItem
 {
    int Id {get;}  
    //other stuff
 }

 public TodoItem:ITodoITem, ITrackTime {}

 public class TodoList:ITodoList,ITrackItem
 {
    ITodoItem Create(title)
    { 
       //create item and add it to collection 
     }
      TodoItem _currentlyTracking;

     void StartTrackTime(int itemId)
     {

        if (_currentlyTracking == null)
        {
           // getItem and call method for item ..
          item.StartTrackTime();
          _currentlyTracking=item;
         }
        else{
           //get item and check to see if it is the same id
           //throw exception if it is not, ignore it if it is
          }
      }
 }

 var list = new TodoList();
 ITodoItem item= list.Create("titel");
 list.StartTrackingTime(item.Id);
 list.StartTrackingTime(otherId); //should throw or whatever handling
```

Everything is contained within the AR (TodoList). One again, this is a rough draft as I'm not fully aware about the context and the domain.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the ToDoList should enforce the constraint since the constraint is defined at the ToDoList level. (Unless it is defined at the user level as you indicated in which case the responsibility would shift there). You can leave the method on the item, but it can reference the parent todo list. The code could look like this:

```
public class ToDoList
{
  public IList<ToDoListItem> Items { get; private set; }

  // factory method creates items as required by ToDoList
  public ToDoListItem Create(string title)
  {
    var item = new ToDoListItem(this, title);
    this.Items.Add(item);
    return item;
  }

  ToDoListItem currentItem;

  public void StartTrackTimeFor(ToDoListItem item) 
  {
    if (this.currentItem != null)
      throw new Exception();
    // could also throw different exception if specified item is current item being tracked
    // start time tracking logic.
    this.currentItem = item;
  }

  public void StopTrackTimeFor(ToDoListItem item)
  {
    if (this.currentItem != item)
      throw new Exception();
    // stop time tracking logic.    
    this.currentItem = null;
  }
}

public class ToDoListItem
{
  public ToDoListItem(ToDoList list, string title) 
  {
    this.ToDoList = list;
    this.Title = title;
  }

  public ToDoList ToDoList { get; private set; }

  public string Title { get; private set; }

  public void StartTrackTime()
  {
    this.ToDoList.StartTrackTimeFor(this);
  } 

  public void StopTrackTime()
  {
    this.ToDoList.StopTrackTimeFor(this);
  }
}
```